# Load thumbnails in TDbCtrlGrid dynamically

Tags: delphi, vcl

I want to load thumbnails in a TDbCtrlGrid dynamically, as preloading takes too much time. So, in DTbCtrlGrid.OnPaintPanel I create the thumbnail and store in the database, so next time the thumbnail needs to be displayed, it does not have to be created again.
However, using Edit/Post in OnPaintPanel seems to result in Recno/PanelIndex getting out of sync.

Refer to [this test project](https://ayuus.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/TDbCtrlGrid-Test.zip) (in which I set a string field's value for simplicity), where TDbGrid's scrollbar keeps repositioning forever. Commenting out Edit/Post makes TDbCtrlGrid behave as expected.

I tried to debug this in Vcl.DBCgrids.pas, but could not find a cause.
Any ideas/suggestions?

Regards, Ronald

code:

unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.Stan.Error,
  FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, Data.DB, Vcl.DBCGrids, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable;
    DBCtrlGrid1: TDBCtrlGrid;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DBCtrlGrid1PaintPanel(DBCtrlGrid: TDBCtrlGrid; Index: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.DBCtrlGrid1PaintPanel(DBCtrlGrid: TDBCtrlGrid; Index: Integer);
begin
  Label1.Caption := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('caption').AsString;

//  FDMemTable1.Edit;
//  FDMemTable1.FieldByName('thumbnail').AsString := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('caption').AsString;
//  FDMemTable1.Post;

  Label2.Caption := FDMemTable1.FieldByName('thumbnail').AsString;
end;



procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  with FDMemTable1 do
  begin
    LogChanges := False;
    CreateDataset;
    Open;
  end;

  with FDMemTable1 do
  try
    AddIndex('Caption', 'caption', '', []);
  finally
    IndexName := 'Caption';
  end;

  for i := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    FDMemTable1.Insert;
    FDMemTable1.FieldByName('caption').AsString := i.ToString;
    FDMemTable1.Post;
  end;

  FDMemTable1.First;
end;

end.
```

unit1.dfm

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 939
  ClientWidth = 1245
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  Position = poDesigned
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  TextHeight = 15
  object DBCtrlGrid1: TDBCtrlGrid
    Left = 245
    Top = 0
    Width = 1000
    Height = 939
    Align = alRight
    ColCount = 5
    DataSource = DataSource1
    PanelHeight = 187
    PanelWidth = 193
    TabOrder = 0
    RowCount = 5
    OnPaintPanel = DBCtrlGrid1PaintPanel
    ExplicitLeft = 474
    ExplicitHeight = 1429
    object Label1: TLabel
      Left = 0
      Top = 172
      Width = 193
      Height = 15
      Align = alBottom
      Alignment = taCenter
      Caption = 'Label1'
      ExplicitTop = 270
      ExplicitWidth = 34
    end
    object Label2: TLabel
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 193
      Height = 172
      Align = alClient
      Alignment = taCenter
      Caption = 'Label2'
      Layout = tlCenter
      ExplicitLeft = 64
      ExplicitTop = 64
      ExplicitWidth = 34
      ExplicitHeight = 15
    end
  end
  object FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable
    FieldDefs = <
      item
        Name = 'Caption'
        DataType = ftString
        Size = 20
      end
      item
        Name = 'Thumbnail'
        DataType = ftString
        Size = 20
      end>
    IndexDefs = <>
    FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode]
    FetchOptions.Mode = fmAll
    ResourceOptions.AssignedValues = [rvSilentMode]
    ResourceOptions.SilentMode = True
    UpdateOptions.AssignedValues = [uvCheckRequired, uvAutoCommitUpdates]
    UpdateOptions.CheckRequired = False
    UpdateOptions.AutoCommitUpdates = True
    StoreDefs = True
    Left = 112
    Top = 280
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = FDMemTable1
    Left = 168
    Top = 368
  end
end
```

Comment: Please note that any code that belongs to your question must be included in your question post. External references may become dysfunctional and are therefore not allowed at SO. Please edit your question and include the code you want to refer to.

Comment: OK, added code for main fom.

Comment: Great! Please also remove the link to the external site, thank you.

Comment: I think I better leave the link as-is for convenience. Downloading the project from my site is easier that copy-paste main form from here.

Comment: Right now you have an endless loop: you edit dataset, dataset notifies (through the data source) visual controls, visual controls update and invalidate, you edit dataset. This isn't specific to TDbCtrlGrid, this is how all data aware controls work. One possible solution is to store the images outsides dataset (eg TObjectDictionary).